# Deploy Spring Boot on local Tomcat in IntelliJ

Tags: angular, spring-boot, tomcat, intellij-idea

Good afternoon

I am newbie to Spring and Spring Boot, usually i work with eclipse IDE and JSF.
I am working in a project that use Angular to the FrontEnd and Spring Boot to the BackEnd.I had the following Maven structure

```
 PARENT
   FRONTEND
     pom.xml
   BACKEND
     pom.xml
pom.xml
```

The FrontEnd produces a webjar and it uses the FrontEnd-Maven-PLugin to build Angular application ,the backend depends on this webJar.
The BackEnd pom.xml has the following configuration :

```
<packaging>war</packaging>
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

I do not want to use of the embedded Tomcat server.
In Intellij i have imported the project being a Maven project,
In Run/Debug configurations besides the default Spring Boot configuration i have created one more that has the "Path to Jar" pointing to the *.war artifact and has the Maven goal configurated to "Maven Goal package".

This way when i run this configuration the FrontEnd is compiled and built.
But either i choose the Spring Boot or this configuration i always see the following log in the Run console

```
 o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
```

I guess this means i am deploying the application in the embedded server.

So my questions is :

1 : How can i deploy and run the application from Intellij in the local Tomcat instead of the embedded.
 2 : Is there a better configuration to Build the front end and deploy it with the backend automatically and out of the box on the Intellij ?

In Eclipse IDE in a JSF project i just add a server to the project and eclipse build and deploy the application to it and manages everything.

Thanks In advance
Best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1 : How can i deploy and run the application from Intellij in the local Tomcat instead of the embedded.**
You already have the scope on provided so the embedded tomcat will not be included in your artefact. IntelliJ has an option to load provided dependencies on the classpath when running though. (it's called `Include dependencies with "Provided` scope" and can be found under the Configuration tab and then in the Environment section of your spring boot run config.

Instead of using the spring boot run config you can also install tomcat locally yourself and use the application server plugin to manage it and deploy to it.

Create a new run config for "Tomcat" and then select "Local". Here you will be able to configure your local tomcat instance so it knows where to deploy it.

**2: Is there a better configuration to Build the front end and deploy it with the backend automatically and out of the box on the Intellij ?**

I can't say if it's better, but I have a similar setup using a different approach. Feel free to check out my repo here: https://github.com/phazebroek/tour-of-rockstars 
The client module contains the frontend angular app and the api is the spring-boot backend. The client uses the `frontend-maven-plugin` to build it and puts the output in a target path. Then my api module utilizes the `maven-resources-plugin` plugin to copy these to the static folder of my spring boot target directory during the maven validate phase. The effect of this is that my angular app is packaged and included in my war file of the backend spring boot app in the static folder so I can serve it's content with spring. So for instance if you run your app on :8080 you can reach your angular app on the same port. e.g. :8080/app/foo.

Do note that you should prefix your REST endpoints with /api for example to avoid collisions with your angular views :-)
If you have a REST endpoint called /foo for example, but you also have a angular widget with the url /foo it will collide. (I did not yet fix that issue for that repository...)

**Extra note: call backend api from angular app in stand-alone mode on different port**

On a side note, the controllers contain a annotation `@CrossOrigin(origins = "*")` to allow requests coming from the angular app when it runs as stand-alone app, on a different port. This should be used in development mode only of course!